# Truncate azure storage file directory/delete azure storage file using wildcard suffix

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, azure-storage-files

I am writing a Powershell script to enable a monthly cleanup of the files in the azure fileshare.

Ideally I would want one script to just truncate the directory/file location.
But will settle for deleting each file individually.

There are about 20 files which are loaded monthly, each file has a unique name and a datetime stamp as a suffix included in the file name.  e.g. *filename_20190121123515*

I've managed to delete a file using the full name, but would need to use wildcard values for the datetime suffix.

What is the correct syntax for what I am trying to achieve? Or how would I truncate the entire folder?

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "AccountName" -SasToken 
"?sv=2015-12-11&si=bss-15D97F9B09D&sr=s&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
Remove-AzStorageFile -ShareName "bss" -Path 
"root/Temp_Clean_up_test_Folder/FileName_%%%%%%%%%%%%%%.csv" -Context 
$context

$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "AccountName" -SasToken 
"?sv=2015-12-11&si=bss-15D97F9B09D&sr=s&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" 
Remove-AzStorageFile -ShareName "bss" -Path 
"root/Temp_Clean_up_test_Folder/FileName_*" -Context $context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cmdlet Remove-AzStorageFile does not support wildcard, you need use a loop method to delete the files one by one.

Sample code like below:

```
$context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName "AccountName" -SasToken "xxx"

# Since the file name has date, you can specify which date to be deleted.
# In this sample, we try to delete the files' name contains 201901

$pattern ="201901"

# iterate all the files, and delete    
Get-AzStorageFile -ShareName "testfolder" -Path "t1/t1sub" -Context $context | Get-AzStorageFile | where {($_.GetType().Name
 -eq "CloudFile") -and ($_.Name -like "*$pattern*")} | Remove-AzStorageFile
```

**Before delete:**

[image]

**After delete**(all the files whose name contains "201901" are deleted):

[image]

Comment: Worked Perfectly! Thank you.